# Xcode 11: Failed to instantiate image from asset catalog (.car file) in a custom bundle on iOS 13

Tags: swift, assets, ios13, resourcebundle, xcode11

Our iOS app has a custom bundle that has an assets catalog (.car file).
This has been the setup since iOS 9. Fetching image assets and using them has not been an issue until now with iOS 13 on Xcode 11 (not sure if it works when app is built with xcode 10 and run on iOS 13).

This is how the bundle is used in the app:
[image: screenshot]

The bundle is fetched using this code:

`let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TheResource", ofType: "bundle")!`
`var bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)`

Now when I print this `bundle` variable I get the following:

```
(lldb) po bundle
▿ Optional<NSBundle>
  - some : NSBundle </Users/xyz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SE8C7E9D-76AF-4564-B21B-78DC990F3D2E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/PD422A04-B4C8-42F0-A5CB-9465AC70D3A2/abc.app/TheResource.bundle> (not yet loaded)
```

```
(lldb) po bundle.loadAndReturnError()
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “TheResource” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSBundlePath=/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SE8C7E9D-76AF-4564-B21B-78DC990F3D2E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/PD422A04-B4C8-42F0-A5CB-9465AC70D3A2/abc.app/TheResource.bundle, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “TheResource” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.}
```

This is the response I get on both a iOS 12 device and a iOS 13 device. But the assets load fine on iOS 12.

I have tried the following things to no avail:
1. Since there is an issue with Xcode 11 throwing the multiple paths generating the same file error, I renamed the .car assets catalog from Assets.car to something more descriptive.
2. called .load() on the bundle variable to try and load it since it kept saying not loaded.
3. Tried to load images with extension, also tried adding some traits and use the `UIImage(named: <name>, in: <bundle>, compatibleWith: <traits>)` method.

Found this [question on apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123490) but thats little different than the behavior I am seeing.

Have no idea why the assets load fine when the app is built with Xcode 11 and run on iOS 12 but do not load when run on iOS 13 devices/simulators.

Any help would be appreciated, I am dumbfounded by this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: No issues with the code, the app compiles fine. The problem is the images do not load at runtime from the bundle on iOS 13

Comment: I had set up breakpoints to check if there are any issues with the bundle object which it seems like there are but I can retrieve images fine on iOS 12. 
This code gets me an UIImage object on iOS 12 but nil with iOS 13 `UIImage(named: "name", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)`

Comment: I see, I have not used that initializer before. What would I pass in for the `AnyClass` parameter?
There is no class associated with the bundle.

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot of how the bundle looks. It just has a json file, strings file and assets.car file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201052/discussion-between-r3d3vil-and-matt).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't fix the problem, but it's worth checking since it's a simple test: have you tried switching build system in File -> Workspace Settings and rebuilding?

Comment: @R3D3vil I have same issue. have you find any solution?

Comment: @YogendraPatel nope. we didnt have very many assets in the bundle. so as a workaround, ended up extracting all images and adding them to xcassets.

Comment: Have you found a solution? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the name you're using to load *case-sensitive* exact to the asset catalog name?

Ran into this problem migrating to Xcode 11 and the problem was in essence

`UIImage(named: "fooImage"...`

when the actual name in the catalog was "FooImage".

So check your *case-sensitive* names first...